# Xcode - How to detect if device is charging at 110V or 220V

Tags: iphone, ios7

Is there any possible way to detect if my device is charging at a 110V plug-in or a 220V one?

Comment: From a software perspective, does it make a difference ?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. Your iOS device doesn't know. It's the actual charger block that converts the input voltage 110/220 to around 5 volts. So the answer to your question is no.